# In scikit learn, how to deal with the data mixed with numerical and nominal value?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-mining, mixed

I know that the computation in scikit-learn is based on NumPy so everything is a matrix or array.

How does this package handle mixed data (numerical and nominal values)?

For example, a product could have the attribute 'color' and 'price', where color is nominal and price is numerical. I notice there is a model called 'DictVectorizer' to numerate the nominal data. For example, two products  are:

```
products = [{'color':'black','price':10}, {'color':'green','price':5}]
```

And the result from 'DictVectorizer' could be:

```
[[1,0,10],
 [0,1,5]]
```

If there are lots of different values for the attribute 'color', the matrix would be very sparse. And long features will degrade the performance of some algorithms, such as decision trees.

**Is there any way to use the nominal value without the need to create dummy codes?**

Comment: It's worth noting that Weka [Instances](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc/weka/core/Instance.html) store nominal values as floating point numbers corresponding to the index of the nominal in the attribute's definition. You could simply follow this same strategy to generate a numeric dataset for use with scikit-learn.

Comment: Thanks a lot for enlarging my knowledge.

Answer (score 6):

The DecisionTree class in scikit-learn will need some refactoring to deal efficiently with high-cardinality categorical features (and maybe even with naturally sparse data such as text TF-IDF vectors).

Nobody is working on that yet AFAIK.

Comment: thanks a lot. In scikit, is there any smart way to do refactoring compared with manual operation?

Comment: My answer states that this current state of affair is a limitation of the current implementation of the Decision Tree in scikit-learn. There is no easy fix I know of to remove that limitation. I don't understand what you call "manual operation".